# Laravel 5.3 session not saving

Tags: php, session, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have upgrade my laravel 5.2 to 5.3 and I am using it just for my webapi. Previously session was working fine. But when I upgrade it to 5.3 my session stop working.

I am using below code

```
Session::put(['webapi_logged_in' => true, 'webapi_loggedin_user' => 'dummydata']);
```

and when I try to get it with another function
`Session::get('webapi_logged_in')` it always return NULL value

Can anyone help me with this

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try with the **request** **object**.

To save data:

```
$request->session()->put('key', 'value');
```

To retrieve data:

```
$request->session()->get('key');
```

Comment: Mark answer if this is helpful

Comment: will only work if the $request is passed into the function

Answer (score 1):

You have to save it, it could be you are exiting early before laravel session handler saves the latest data into session than in memory.

try something like `Session::save();` after put